# Addition, Add Multiple textbox using Javascript function

Tags: javascript, html, function

I have this problem that I add 8 textbox and it works fine but when i add more textbox like 16 textbox it doesnt add the last textbox. does anyone encoutered this problem? Thanks in Advance.

[Live Link: JAVASCRIPT.](http://jsbin.com/OJOlARe/186/edit)

```
function sum() {

        var basicpay = document.getElementById('basicpay').value;
        var overtime = document.getElementById('overtime').value;
        var regularholiday = document.getElementById('regularholiday').value;
        var specialholiday = document.getElementById('specialholiday').value;
        var allowanceday = document.getElementById('allowanceday').value;
        var others = document.getElementById('others').value;
        var grosspay = document.getElementById('grosspay').value;
        var monthpay13 = document.getElementById('monthpay13').value;
        var absent = document.getElementById('absent').value;
        var tardiness = document.getElementById('tardiness').value;
        var sss = document.getElementById('sss').value;
        var pagibig = document.getElementById('pagibig').value;
        var philhealth = document.getElementById('philhealth').value;
        var cashadvances = document.getElementById('cashadvances').value;
        var withholdingtax = document.getElementById('withholdingtax').value;
        var others = document.getElementById('others').value;



        var result = 

        parseInt(basicpay) + 
        parseInt(overtime) +
        parseInt(regularholiday) +
        parseInt(specialholiday) +
        parseInt(allowanceday) +
        parseInt(others) +
        parseInt(grosspay) +
        parseInt(absent) + 
        parseInt(tardiness) +
        parseInt(sss) +
        parseInt(pagibig) +
        parseInt(philhealth) +
        parseInt(cashadvances) +
        parseInt(withholdingtax) +
        parseInt(others) +
        parseInt(monthpay13);

        if (!isNaN(result)) {
            document.getElementById('totalincome').value = result;
        }
        }
```

Comment: Why are you setting `others` twice and adding it two times in the `result` formula?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're using the same ID `others` for field 6 and field 16. Give them different IDs

```
16.<input type="text" id="others1" Placeholder="More others"  onkeyup="sum();" /><br>
```

And change the JS:

```
var others1 = var others = document.getElementById('others1').value;

var result = 

parseInt(basicpay) + 
parseInt(overtime) +
parseInt(regularholiday) +
parseInt(specialholiday) +
parseInt(allowanceday) +
parseInt(others) +
parseInt(grosspay) +
parseInt(absent) + 
parseInt(tardiness) +
parseInt(sss) +
parseInt(pagibig) +
parseInt(philhealth) +
parseInt(cashadvances) +
parseInt(withholdingtax) +
parseInt(others1) +
parseInt(monthpay13);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that problem is because your `6` and `16` number textbox has same ID.

Change your ID of textbox number `16` and It should work.

Comment: HAHAHAHAHA! NICE ONE SIR! CASE CLOSE! Thanks Alot guys!

Answer (score 0):

The issue happens on the very last field. This is caused by the fact that you have two boxes with the same `ID`. To fix that change the last box ID `from others to others2`. And also change your variable called others to others2 because there are two variables called `others`